# EE Upgrade Issue: MB_ENABLED

Tags: error, upgrade

On the last couple of EE upgrades I've received a PHP error regarding MB_ENABLED:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Use of undefined constant MB_ENABLED - assumed 'MB_ENABLED'
>
> Filename: libraries/Encrypt.php
>
> Line Number: 367

This is repeated for each instance of `MB_ENABLED` in the system/codeigniter/system/libraries/Encrypt.php file.

If I wrap each instance of `MB_ENABLED` in single quotes then it resolves the issue but having to do this on each upgrade is a little annoying.

It seems to be [mentioned on the EllisLab forums](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/238342/) also but the solution is again to modify core files. Is this a bug? Has anyone encountered this issue in upgrading recently?

Comment: I just upgraded from 2.5.x to 2.8.1, and am getting the same errors. I changed line 47 of /system/codeigniter/system/core/Utf8.php to "AND $CFG->item('charset') == 'UTF-8' OR 'utf-8'" and that got rid of the errors. The client's server doesn't have iconv enabled and I don't see this in the EECMS system reqs. Also, the server passed the ee wizard tests. Is this an issue with EE or my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been a long standing bug where the constant just wasn't defined. It's ***finally*** squished in EE 2.9:

> "Fixed a bug where MB_ENABLED was undefined"

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen this. I'm guessing there is something in your environment that EE doesn't like.

I found a PyroCMS thread which mentions this error. That CMS is (was) build on CodeIgniter. It mentions in that thread that you need to have the iconv extension installed. This extension is enabled by default in recent versions of PHP, so that would likely make this an uncommon error.

https://forum.pyrocms.com/discussion/comment/20605/#Comment_20605

Check your PHPinfo to see if this extension has been enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I just got this error when using channel:form, enabling 'iconv extension' fixed the issue.